# How to kill process repeat it self every one second in windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, malware

I'm infected with some malware and I found the virus and I removed it .

When I open **taskmanager** I still found the process for virus still active background.

I use **windows server 2012** and I only have **freesshd** terminal to interact with windows so I use **powershell** command :

```
Stop-Process -Name procname -Force
```

But it still shows up in **taskmanager** and repeats it self every second .

How can I kill it using powershell or cmd ?

Comment: What did you use to remove the virus?  What was the virus called?

Comment: @somebadhat , its a meterpreter shell . #metasploit

Comment: You have a compromised server. At a minimum, you should take it off your network, build another one, try to figure out how it got compromised and ensure that at least that gap is closed on your new server. Chances are that whatever got on your server has been able to get to other machines as well. Depending on what and if you are willing to pay for peace of mind, I would suggest finding a firm that specializes in this (forensics/cleanup/restore services).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.  :)

1. try removing it again, because it's not really gone.
2. no warranties, this is a virus and could be temperamental.

That said, try this and maybe tweak it to suit your purposes:

```
$logfile = "C:\temp\KillProcesses.txt"
$procName = "<process name here>"

while ($true) {
    # get the process
    $killproc = get-ciminstance win32_process | where commandline -imatch $procName        

    # try it first with taskkill
    if ($killproc.ProcessId) {
        invoke-command -ScriptBlock {cmd /c taskkill /f /PID $killproc.ProcessId} > $logfile 2>&1
    } else {
        "<log message>" > $logfile
    }

    # try it again with Powershell
        if ($killproc.ProcessId) {
            Stop-Process -Id $killproc.ProcessId -Force > $logfile 2>&1
    } else {
        "<log message>" > $logfile
    }


    # move it to another name or try to delete it or something
    if ($killproc) {
        $origpath = ($killproc.CommandLine).tostring().replace("`"","").trim() #might need to parse this for the full path to filename
        $killpath = "$origpath.bad"  

        Move-Item $origpath $killpath > $logfile 2>&1
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

As you learn more, you might use try/catch around the commands, or even learn to convert something like this to a running a service.

This answers the question, but I still think it's a better solution to get rid of the virus.  Not sure you want this running all the time on your system.  :)

Comment: hey @adam18 , thanks , but im not sure if i can use this , because its an back server and i can run any script on it .

Comment: Not what "an back" server is, but if you can run the 'stop-process' command, I think you can run task kill, and run the CimInstance command to find and then rename the executable.